# How do I replace a small number of index labels in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, indexing

Assume these are 4 rows from a DataFrame (df) with many rows.

```
       a  b    
AB01   1  5
DE44   2  6
GH33   3  7
JK05   4  8
```

My objective is to change the index labels.
Specifically, I want to change DE44 to DE55, and GH33 to QVXYZ.

This works:

```
df.index.values[1] ='DE55'
df.index.values[2] ='QVXYZ'
df
       a  b    
AB01   1  5
DE55   2  6
QVXYZ  3  7
JK05   4  8
```

But I cheated.  I know that the labels DE55 and GH33 are on rows
df.iloc[1] and df.iloc[2] of this very small sample.

If the DataFrame has many rows and I don't what row the labels are on
that I want to change, how do I do that?  Is there a way to get the index integer from the label without explicitly iterating row by row?

Comment: Please show data and code that demonstrate your problem and state the desired output. You should also show some of your own effort. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Dictionaries to efficiently replace index labels without the need to know in advance what row of a DataFrame the labels are on.  The trick is to first swap rows and columns.

The general approach is

```
1. use df.transpose() to swap the index and column heading axes
2. use df.rename() to change the row index labels (now column headings!)
3. use df.transpose() to revert the axes to where they were.
```

Example:
Assume we have the following DataFrame and want to change index labels A, B and G.

```
df starts out:
--------------
  col1   col2  col3  col4
A  foo    one     0     0
B  bar    one     1     2
C  foo    two     2     4
D  bar  three     3     6
E  foo    two     4     8
F  bar    two     5    10
G  foo    one     6    12
H  foo  three     7    14
```

Create a dictionary with the labels to change.
Name value pairs of the dictionary will be structured as

> { 'index label to change' : 'what to change it to' }

```
oldNewRowXref = {'A':'was row A',
                 'B':'was row B', 
                 'G':'was G'}
```

The following line of code chains together the 3 steps above and
changes the index labels as prescribed in the oldNewRowXref dictionary:

> df.transpose().rename(columns=oldNewRowXref).transpose()

```
df index labels changed:
------------------------
          xxx1   col2 col3 lastCol
was row A  foo    one    0       0
was row B  bar    one    1       2
C          foo    two    2       4
D          bar  three    3       6
E          foo    two    4       8
F          bar    two    5      10
was G      foo    one    6      12
H          foo  three    7      14
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering this:

```
l = ["March","b"]

[i if i != "March" else "Mar" for i in l]
```

Returns

```
['Mar', 'b']
```

How about:

```
df.index = [i if i != "March" else "Mar" for i in df.index]
```